# Invalid rule in CodeIgniter 4

Tags: php, updates, codeigniter-4, validationrules

I'm trying to create an update page for users. The firstname and lastname are getting updated successfully, but when I try to update the password it gaves me an error which says that the rule is not a valid rule. I can't understand what is the problem. Here is my profile method.

```
public function profile()
    {
        $data = [];
        helper(['form']);

        $model = new UserModel();

        if ($this->request->getMethod() == 'post') {
            $rules = [
                'firstname'  => 'required|min_length[3]|max_length[20]',
                'lastname'   => 'required|min_length[3]|max_length[20]',
            ];

            if ($this->request->getPost('password') != '') {
                    $rules['password'] = 'required|min_length[8]|max_length[255]|';
                    $rules['password_confirm'] = 'matches[password]';
                }

            if (! $this->validate($rules)) {
                $data['validation'] = $this->validator;
            } else {

                $newData = [
                    'id'           => session()->get('id'),
                    'firstname'    => $this->request->getPost('firstname'),
                    'lastname'     => $this->request->getPost('lastname'),
                ];
                
                if ($this->request->getPost('password') != '') {
                    $newData['password'] = $this->request->getPost('password');
                }

                $model->save($newData);

                session()->setFlashData('success', 'Successfully Updated');
                return redirect()->to('/profile');
            }

        }

        $data['user'] = $model->where('id', session()->get('id'))->first();

        echo view('templates/logreg/header', $data);
        echo view('profile');
        echo view('templates/logreg/footer');
    }
```

Comment: _"it gaves me an error which says that the rule is not a valid rule"_ - What rule is it complaining about? Please always share all error messages "as is".

Comment: @Magnus Eriksson It says "CodeIgniter\Validation\Exceptions\ValidationException
is not a valid rule." And then gives me "SYSTEMPATH\Validation\Validation.php at line 314" error in this line, but it's a file in system and i can't understand what i wrote wrong in my file.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the last pipeline character in this line:

$rules['password'] = 'required|min_length[8]|max_length[255]|';

->
$rules['password'] = 'required|min_length[8]|max_length[255]';